# How to derive Slime Mould Equations

Tags: stochastic-processes, algorithms, nonlinear-optimization, biology, artificial-intelligence

As shown in https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Slime_Mould_Algorithm, we have the Slime Mould equations for Approach food and Wrap food. I do not know how to derive these equations. Please help me or refer me any papers/books for deriving and explaining these equations.

Comment: Did you look at any of the 10 papers referenced in the article?

Comment: yes, I have seen these papers. but I do not know how to derive p, a, W.